# how to disable autoslider in materializecss?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I have tried `autoplay:false` and `autoStart:false` but it doesn't support it. Please suggest me.

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/78125vs0/115/)

```
 $('.sliderone').slider({
    full_width: true,
    indicators:true,
    height:400,
    interval:1000,
    autoplay:false
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any `option` provided as of now by the team by you can <kbd>**`hack`**</kbd> it using below method:

```
$('.sliderone').slider('pause'); //just pause the slider once its loaded
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/78125vs0/116/)**

**Note**

> - Since it is the developing version of framework you can expect this feature in future.
> - This again gets started once you click on any `indicators`. So I would suggest to write a click event to `indicators` making pause
>     again after the slider is moved.

```
$('.indicator-item').on('click',function(){
    $('.sliderone').slider('pause');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/78125vs0/117/)**

---

**UPDATE**

Again there isn't any documentation on this, but with `jquery` your can pretty much achieve this as below:

```
$(".indicators .indicator-item").each(function(key,value){
    //iterate through each indicator-item
    //key will be starting from 0,1,2,3 etc., and goes to number of indicators present
    var img=$('<img/>',{
      'src':$('.slides img').eq(key).css('background-image').replace('url(','').replace(')','')
    });
    //create an image tag as above and set its src from each image's background-image property value present inside
    //.slides element and get using its index with the help of eq(key)
    //say key=0 at first iteration and when I say eq(0) this will get 1st image
    //similarly second, third and gets appended to its respective indicators
    img.appendTo($(this))
});
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/78125vs0/122/)**

Comment: Thanks. Can we able to use thumbnail images instead of that default indicators ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write big interval, like `interval:1000000`. It's a crutch, but may help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.slider').slider({
    interval:100000
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To provide the best answer possible for other people who may read it, could you include a short description about how this code will answer the original question?